# PHP: isset Leads to a 406 Not Acceptable After User Registration

Tags: php, apache

Let me start by saying (a) I have a web hosting account with JustHost and (b) I did a lot of Googling to try to find a connection specifically between isset and the 406. I found lots of 406 issues that were not related to `isset`. I also found this link (http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/HTTP_Exception_406) but overall this did not help.

I'm building my 2nd php site and I had thought I had come across a fair number of errors. However, on my registration page I got a new (for me) one today:

```
406 Not Acceptable: An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security
```

I found the culprit....when the user registers, I was checking the registration form as follows (abridged):

```
if (isset($_POST['registrationbutton'])) {

    if (!isset($_POST['fullname']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $M = 'Please fill out all of the fields in the form to sign up!';
    } else if //etc.

    }

header('Location: SignUp.php?msgpost='.urlencode($M));

}//end first if

$NewPostMessage = (isset($_GET['msgpost'])) ? $_GET['msgpost'] : null;//alerts the user to the message $M post-registration attempt after body onload
```

After this, clicking on any link in the Navigation Menu takes the user to the 406 error page.

I changed this offending line:

```
if (!isset($_POST['fullname']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {
```

to this:

```
if (!$_POST['fullname'] || !$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password']) {
```

and no more 406.

I am trying to learn as much about php as I can. Can anybody please explain why `!isset($_POST['var'])` might have led to the 406?

Comment: Contact your web host. This confusing error message is probably the result of an overeager web application firewall.

Comment: OK...will do. Their customer support is pretty knowledgeable.

Comment: isset() cannot possibly issue an http header. all it does it check if a particular variable/array key exists or not. If a 406 got issued because of isset(), then it's some code within the `if() { ...}` block that did it, and it's the decision based on isset's results that caused it.

Comment: @Marc B, literally the only thing I changed was all the !isset statements had the isset removed. Of note is that when the header (when I was having issues originally) was changed to header('Location: SignUp.php') this also stopped the error (but this was a hack solution since I need $M to be appended to URL)

Comment: all that does is change the code path. basically it'd wwould've gone from `if(true) { send 406 }` to `if (false) { send 406}` or something like that. but isset() can literally NOT send an http header. it's code that comes AFTER the if that would've done it. all you did was change the path php takes through your code.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: Removing the `isset` is quite enough to trigger a notice (in cases where your code hasn't already ensured the post params are there), which would cause (possibly incomplete/incorrect) headers to be sent out.  That should really be *causing* problems, not fixing them.

Comment: OK...I will try and use all of your input to figure this out. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK...found it. The word "javascript" is apparently a restricted word for appending to the URL. Any use of this word in the message ($M) appended to the URL led to the 406.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: That kinda sounds like mod_security being stupidly set up.  It shouldn't be choking on any normal word.  Now, if it were immediately followed by a colon, i could see it possibly triggering something.  That's still a bit boneheaded, in my opinion (it should be more specific than just filtering out "javascript:")...but it does reduce the possibility of script injection, at the cost of making it harder to discuss web development.  :P